# Is it possible to call a handler in main function?

Tags: xcode, applescript-objc

Is it possible to call `myHandler()` in main function ? My thought is to automatically call a handler at the beginning. THX

main.m:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <AppleScriptObjC/AppleScriptObjC.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadAppleScriptObjectiveCScripts];
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

AppDelegate.applescript:

```
script AppDelegate

on myHandler()
    say "Welcome,sir."
end myHandler

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(sender)
    -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate_

end script
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use that command as a handler. Just insert the command after this line…  on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(sender).  So your code should look like this in the AppDelegate.applescript:

```
script AppDelegate

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(sender)
    say "Welcome,sir."
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate_

end script
```

Comment: @Novice I am curious to see how my suggestion worked out for you.